# Logic Circuit Question

Tags: boolean-algebra

1) Write the boolean expression after every GATE 
2) Write the boolean expression of GATE 3
3) Try to simplify the boolean expression of GATE3

[image: Circuit]

I need to know if what I did its right + your advice if there is another way to answer those questions.
1) $GATE_1 = (A'B)' = A+B'$ |$ GATE_2 = 1 ⊕ C$

2) $GATE_3 = ((A+B')+0+C')'$

3) $A'BC$

Comment: yes everything is correct

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Yes you are correct and I used the same method to reach the answers as you have above.

Comment: Thanks,I have another question about multiplexer and dont know if to post that, if I have MUX 24:1 , how much data select lines will be?

Comment: Sorry that's beyond me. Post it, i'm there will be someone on here more than happy to help.